# Specifying specific jar files with maven

Tags: java, maven

in ~/.m2/path/to/jarfiles there are to jar files. One is dependencyName.jar and the other is dependencyName-runtime.jar I am trying to use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy the runtime version of the jar but it keeps copying the regular version of the jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.dependency.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                                <version>${code.coverage.jacoco.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `runtime` is a classifier, you should add

```
<classifier>runtime</classifier>
```

to your `artifactItem`.